# What is the greatest creation of Allah?

Tags: allah, creation

Yesterday I was reading an article which stated that the arsh (kursi) of Allah is the greatest of all creations.But we know that prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is the greatest creation of Allah..
So please clear this fact...

Comment: Perhaps the misunderstanding is because of a different meaning of "greatest"? It can both mean "biggest" and "best." The article probably meant the arsh is the *biggest* creation. And Muhammad (SAW) is the *best* creation.